# Deferred subquery loading SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty familiar with SQLAlchemy and its loading strategies but I'm banging my head against the wall trying to find a solution for the following problem:

I have an object `Job` which is referenced by another object `Impression`. As you can imagine, every `Impression` has a `job_id` and there is a big amount of impressions (millions) and a lot per `Job` (few hundreds). These few hundreds are naturally a bit slow to load (as well in Postgres and in SQLAlchemy) and I'd like to optimize the loading of these.

Now, I'd like to define my loading strategy for the relation and I cannot choose from the existing ones:

```
class Impression(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'impressions_tb'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())
    job_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('job_tb.id', name='impressions_tb_job_id_fkey', ondelete='cascade'),
                   nullable=False)
    job = db.relationship('Job', lazy='joined', backref=db.backref(lazy='IDONOTKNOW', name='detailed_impressions'))
```

As far as I know, my options are:

`lazy loading`: cool (because only called when I really need it) but I get the N+1 problem which is dumb in the case of lots related elements.

`joined loading`: very good as well but most of the time, I do NOT need to have the detailed impressions since I have them aggregated somewhere else.

`subquery loading` or `select IN loading`: exactly what I'm looking for but not eager, I need to have them triggered via a call code (only if I need the detailed impressions and call `job.detailed_impressions` the subquery should be triggered).

`no loading` or `raise loading`: is what I'm using at the moment to avoid having to load the detailed impressions.

My question is: is there something that I'm missing? Should I use a `@property` to solve this problem? Isn't it covered by the `Relation` object? How do you solve that issue in your apps?